# PHP - file handle instead of path

Tags: php, phpmailer, file-handling, filehandle

I have a **3rd party function** that receives a **file path only**.
I have **no file path** but I have a **file handle**.
Is it possible to pass the **handle** in such a way it would be **treated as path**?

In particular:

I am using **PHPMailer** library for sending emails.
I want to attach files to emails and using `$mail->addAttachment()` which accepts file paths only.
The files I am going to send are generated on the fly.
I would like to generate such a file and pass it to this function without being actually created on the server. There are to many files and it becomes problematically to clean the trails.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [addStringAttachment() method](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment):

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($fileContent,$fileNameToDisplay,$encoding,$type).
```